# Cascade Server - Velocity: $_XPathTool.selectNodes() - Using variables instead of string for second arg

Tags: xml, xpath, velocity

I have to iterate through a collection of nodes, and in that collection I need to get another collection of nodes.

I normally do:

```
#set ( $content = $_XPathTool.selectNodes($contentRoot, "string/to/path") )
```

I then need to do something like this:

```
#foreach ( $section in $content )
  $set ( $items = $_XPathTool.selectNodes($contentRoot, $section) )
#end
```

Needless to say, that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer:

```
#foreach ( $section in $content )
  $set ( $items = $_XPathTool.selectNodes($contentRoot, $section) )
  #set ( $itemNode = $section.getChild("nodeContainer") )
  #set ( $individualNode = $_XPathTool.selectNodes($nodeContainer, "//individualNode") )    
#end
```

Comment: You don't need the first line inside your `foreach` loop. You can also eliminate the second line in your `foreach` in this example and combine the `nodeContainer` into your XPath expression: `$_XPathTool.selectNodes($section, "nodeContainer//individualNode")`. Also, make sure your set directives all start with a # and not a $. Feel free to contact us (Hannon Hill) directly for dedicated support.